# Atomikos silently rollback transaction without any Exception

Tags: timeout, rollback, atomikos, transactionmanager

I am testing global transaction and timeout in atomikos. I created test where I am inserting data to first db and then call procedure in second db so I am using global transaction. Here is my test service code:

```
@Transactional(timeout = 5)
public void rollbackTest2x() {
    SqlSession sqlLogSession = getSession(LOGRWX);
    wsZadostDao.insert(sqlLogSession, new Record().withUUID(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));

    SqlSession sqlSession = getSession(REFRWX);
    procDelayDao.procDelay(sqlSession, new ProcDelay().withSecond(10));
    // procDelayDao.procDelay(sqlSession, new ProcDelay().withSecond(10));
}
```

This test throw no exception but the data are rollback. There is just exception in Atomikos `PooledAlarmTimer` which is not propagated to main thread. So my test ends OK but data are not inserted. Any idea how should I fix it ?

```
2018-11-12 11:57:39.948 [main] DEBUG o.sqlproc.engine.spring.SpringQuery - callUpdate, query=call PROC_DELAY(?)
2018-11-12 11:57:40.021 [main] TRACE c.a.d.pool.AbstractXPooledConnection - an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): registering listener atomikos connection pool 'REFRW1X'
2018-11-12 11:57:40.023 [main] TRACE com.atomikos.thread.TaskManager - ThreadFactory: creating new thread: Atomikos:6
2018-11-12 11:57:40.025 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean - AtomikosDataSoureBean 'REFRW1X': init done.
2018-11-12 11:57:40.025 [main] TRACE c.a.i.i.CompositeTransactionManagerImp - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:40.025 [main] TRACE c.a.d.pool.AbstractXPooledConnection - an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): updating last time acquired
2018-11-12 11:57:40.025 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosXAPooledConnection - an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): testing connection with query [SELECT 1 FROM DUAL]
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosXAPooledConnection - an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): connection tested OK
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosXAPooledConnection - an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): creating connection proxy...
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] DEBUG c.a.jdbc.JdbcConnectionProxyHelper - setting isolation level to 2
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.SessionHandleState - a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): notifySessionBorrowed
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.TransactionContext - a TransactionContext: changing to state com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.NotInBranchStateHandler@6f07d414
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.i.i.CompositeTransactionManagerImp - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] DEBUG c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12: calling toString...
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12: toString returning oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.d.pool.AbstractXPooledConnection - an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): returning proxy oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool - atomikos connection pool 'REFRW1X': current size: 0/1
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.i.i.CompositeTransactionManagerImp - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] DEBUG c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12: calling toString...
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12: toString returning oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean - AtomikosDataSoureBean 'REFRW1X': returning oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.i.i.CompositeTransactionManagerImp - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12: notifyBeforeUse a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s)
2018-11-12 11:57:40.026 [main] TRACE c.a.i.i.CompositeTransactionManagerImp - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:40.027 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.SessionHandleState - a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): checking XA context for transaction com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp@f881a272
2018-11-12 11:57:40.027 [main] TRACE c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001 entering state: ACTIVE
2018-11-12 11:57:40.027 [main] DEBUG c.a.i.imp.CompositeTransactionImp - addParticipant ( XAResourceTransaction: 726F622D6170702D3738373963323832356230323338393833363738356563666637636132633434313534323032303235393538363030303031:726F622D6170702D373837396332383235623032333839383336373835656366663763613263343432 ) for transaction my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:40.027 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.XAResourceTransaction - XAResourceTransaction: 726F622D6170702D3738373963323832356230323338393833363738356563666637636132633434313534323032303235393538363030303031:726F622D6170702D373837396332383235623032333839383336373835656366663763613263343432: about to switch to XAResource oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource@223967ea
2018-11-12 11:57:40.027 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.XAResourceTransaction - XAResourceTransaction my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c442: switched to XAResource oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource@223967ea
2018-11-12 11:57:40.027 [main] DEBUG c.a.d.xa.XAResourceTransaction - XAResource.start ( 726F622D6170702D3738373963323832356230323338393833363738356563666637636132633434313534323032303235393538363030303031:726F622D6170702D373837396332383235623032333839383336373835656366663763613263343432 , XAResource.TMNOFLAGS ) on resource REFRW1X represented by XAResource instance oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource@223967ea
2018-11-12 11:57:40.027 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.TransactionContext - a TransactionContext: changing to state com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEnlistedStateHandler@4a6a6a69
2018-11-12 11:57:40.027 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12: detected transaction com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp@f881a272
2018-11-12 11:57:40.027 [main] DEBUG c.a.i.imp.CompositeTransactionImp - registerSynchronization ( com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy$JdbcRequeueSynchronization@f881a272 ) for transaction my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:40.027 [main] DEBUG c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12: calling prepareCall({ call PROC_DELAY(?)})...
2018-11-12 11:57:40.048 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12: prepareCall returning oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper@16ac4d3d
2018-11-12 11:57:44.703 [Atomikos:4] WARN  c.a.icatch.imp.ActiveStateHandler - Transaction my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001 has timed out - rolling back...
2018-11-12 11:57:44.704 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001 entering state: ABORTING
2018-11-12 11:57:44.708 [Atomikos:4] TRACE com.atomikos.thread.TaskManager - ThreadFactory: creating new thread: Atomikos:7
2018-11-12 11:57:44.708 [Atomikos:4] TRACE com.atomikos.thread.TaskManager - ThreadFactory: creating new thread: Atomikos:8
2018-11-12 11:57:44.710 [Atomikos:8] DEBUG c.a.d.xa.XAResourceTransaction - XAResource.end ( 726F622D6170702D3738373963323832356230323338393833363738356563666637636132633434313534323032303235393538363030303031:726F622D6170702D373837396332383235623032333839383336373835656366663763613263343432 , XAResource.TMSUCCESS ) on resource REFRW1X represented by XAResource instance oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource@223967ea
2018-11-12 11:57:44.711 [Atomikos:7] DEBUG c.a.d.xa.XAResourceTransaction - XAResource.end ( 726F622D6170702D3738373963323832356230323338393833363738356563666637636132633434313534323032303235393538363030303031:726F622D6170702D373837396332383235623032333839383336373835656366663763613263343431 , XAResource.TMSUCCESS ) on resource LOGRW1X represented by XAResource instance oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource@446c8c72
2018-11-12 11:57:50.055 [Atomikos:7] DEBUG c.a.d.xa.XAResourceTransaction - XAResource.rollback ( 726F622D6170702D3738373963323832356230323338393833363738356563666637636132633434313534323032303235393538363030303031:726F622D6170702D373837396332383235623032333839383336373835656366663763613263343431 ) on resource LOGRW1X represented by XAResource instance oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource@446c8c72
2018-11-12 11:57:50.058 [Atomikos:8] DEBUG c.a.d.xa.XAResourceTransaction - XAResource.rollback ( 726F622D6170702D3738373963323832356230323338393833363738356563666637636132633434313534323032303235393538363030303031:726F622D6170702D373837396332383235623032333839383336373835656366663763613263343432 ) on resource REFRW1X represented by XAResource instance oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CXAResource@223967ea
2018-11-12 11:57:50.059 [main] DEBUG o.sqlproc.engine.spring.SpringQuery - callUpdate, number of updated rows=-1
2018-11-12 11:57:50.059 [main] DEBUG o.sqlproc.engine.SqlProcedureEngine - << callUpdate, result=-1
2018-11-12 11:57:50.059 [main] TRACE org.my.app.db.ProcDelayDao - sql procDelay result: -1
2018-11-12 11:57:50.060 [main] TRACE c.a.i.i.CompositeTransactionManagerImp - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:50.060 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001 entering state: TERMINATED
2018-11-12 11:57:50.060 [main] DEBUG c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@72eed547: close()...
2018-11-12 11:57:50.060 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AbstractConnectionProxy - Forcing close of pending statement: oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@37b1149b
2018-11-12 11:57:50.060 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.SessionHandleState - a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): entering notifySessionClosed
2018-11-12 11:57:50.060 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.SessionHandleState - a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): delegating session close to a TransactionContext
2018-11-12 11:57:50.061 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.TransactionContext - a TransactionContext: changing state to com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEndedStateHandler@5409dfdd
2018-11-12 11:57:50.061 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.TransactionContext - a TransactionContext: changing to state com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEndedStateHandler@5409dfdd
2018-11-12 11:57:50.061 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@72eed547: closed.
2018-11-12 11:57:50.061 [main] TRACE c.a.i.i.CompositeTransactionManagerImp - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:50.061 [main] DEBUG c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12: close()...
2018-11-12 11:57:50.061 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AbstractConnectionProxy - Forcing close of pending statement: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper@16ac4d3d
2018-11-12 11:57:50.061 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.SessionHandleState - a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): entering notifySessionClosed
2018-11-12 11:57:50.061 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.SessionHandleState - a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): delegating session close to a TransactionContext
2018-11-12 11:57:50.061 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.TransactionContext - a TransactionContext: changing state to com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEndedStateHandler@45f9d394
2018-11-12 11:57:50.061 [main] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.TransactionContext - a TransactionContext: changing to state com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEndedStateHandler@45f9d394
2018-11-12 11:57:50.061 [main] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12: closed.
2018-11-12 11:57:50.061 [main] TRACE c.a.i.i.CompositeTransactionManagerImp - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:50.062 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001 : stopping timer...
2018-11-12 11:57:50.062 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001 : disposing statehandler TERMINATED...
2018-11-12 11:57:50.062 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Coordinator my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001 : disposed.
2018-11-12 11:57:50.062 [main] TRACE c.a.i.i.CompositeTransactionManagerImp - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:50.062 [main] TRACE c.a.i.i.CompositeTransactionManagerImp - getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:50.064 [main] DEBUG c.a.i.imp.CompositeTransactionImp - commit() done (by application) of transaction my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:50.064 [main] TRACE c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - prepare() of Coordinator  my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001 returning READONLY
2018-11-12 11:57:50.066 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp - Error during setRollbackOnly
java.lang.IllegalStateException: my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001 is no longer active but in state TERMINATED
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.addParticipant(CoordinatorImp.java:383)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.setRollbackOnly(CoordinatorImp.java:703)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TransactionStateHandler.setRollbackOnly(TransactionStateHandler.java:260)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.setRollbackOnly(CompositeTransactionImp.java:262)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.entered(CompositeTransactionImp.java:343)
    at com.atomikos.finitestates.FSMImp.notifyListeners(FSMImp.java:166)
    at com.atomikos.finitestates.FSMImp.setState(FSMImp.java:256)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.setState(CoordinatorImp.java:312)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.setStateHandler(CoordinatorImp.java:222)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorStateHandler.rollbackFromWithinCallback(CoordinatorStateHandler.java:506)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.ActiveStateHandler$1.doRollback(ActiveStateHandler.java:85)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorStateHandler.rollbackWithAfterCompletionNotification(CoordinatorStateHandler.java:563)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.ActiveStateHandler.onTimeout(ActiveStateHandler.java:80)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.alarm(CoordinatorImp.java:650)
    at com.atomikos.timing.PooledAlarmTimer.notifyListeners(PooledAlarmTimer.java:95)
    at com.atomikos.timing.PooledAlarmTimer.run(PooledAlarmTimer.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-11-12 11:57:50.067 [Atomikos:4] DEBUG c.a.i.imp.CompositeTransactionImp - setRollbackOnly() called for transaction my-app-7879c2825b02389836785ecff7ca2c44154202025958600001
2018-11-12 11:57:50.068 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@72eed547: detected termination of transaction com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp@f881a272
2018-11-12 11:57:50.069 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.TransactionContext - a TransactionContext: changing to state com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.TerminatedStateHandler@3a06f087
2018-11-12 11:57:50.069 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.SessionHandleState - a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): all contexts terminated, firing TerminatedEvent for a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s)
2018-11-12 11:57:50.069 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosXAPooledConnection - SessionHandleState terminated, firing XPooledConnectionTerminated event for an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s)
2018-11-12 11:57:50.069 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.d.pool.AbstractXPooledConnection - an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): updating last time released
2018-11-12 11:57:50.069 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.d.pool.AbstractXPooledConnection - an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): notifying listener: atomikos connection pool 'LOGRW1X'
2018-11-12 11:57:50.070 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool - atomikos connection pool 'LOGRW1X': connection an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s) became available, notifying potentially waiting threads
2018-11-12 11:57:50.070 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.d.pool.AbstractXPooledConnection - an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): updating last time released
2018-11-12 11:57:50.070 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@40faff12: detected termination of transaction com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp@f881a272
2018-11-12 11:57:50.070 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.TransactionContext - a TransactionContext: changing to state com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.TerminatedStateHandler@38415c0d
2018-11-12 11:57:50.070 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.d.xa.session.SessionHandleState - a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): all contexts terminated, firing TerminatedEvent for a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s)
2018-11-12 11:57:50.070 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.jdbc.AtomikosXAPooledConnection - SessionHandleState terminated, firing XPooledConnectionTerminated event for an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s)
2018-11-12 11:57:50.070 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.d.pool.AbstractXPooledConnection - an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): updating last time released
2018-11-12 11:57:50.070 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.d.pool.AbstractXPooledConnection - an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): notifying listener: atomikos connection pool 'REFRW1X'
2018-11-12 11:57:50.070 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool - atomikos connection pool 'REFRW1X': connection an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s) became available, notifying potentially waiting threads
2018-11-12 11:57:50.070 [Atomikos:4] TRACE c.a.d.pool.AbstractXPooledConnection - an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): updating last time released
```

**UPDATE:**

I dont understand this atomikos code. I have two participants in transaction with state: `TerminatedState` which return READ_ONLY in prepare method so there is no commit and no exception is thrown

```
protected void terminate ( boolean commit ) throws HeurRollbackException,
        HeurMixedException, SysException, java.lang.SecurityException,
        HeurCommitException, HeurHazardException, RollbackException,
        IllegalStateException

{    
    synchronized ( fsm_ ) {
        if ( commit ) {
            if ( participants_.size () <= 1 ) {
                commit ( true );
            } else {
                int prepareResult = prepare ();
                // make sure to only do commit if NOT read only
                if ( prepareResult != Participant.READ_ONLY )
                    commit ( false );
            }
        } else {
            rollback ();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the work is READ_ONLY then there is nothing to commit. It means your SQL did not change any records.